# Using non-anonymous function inside jQuery's 'filter()`

Tags: jquery, filter, refactoring

Im using jQuerys `filter()` inside of a `for loop` and i want to refactor my code to not use an anonymous function, for performance reasons.

What i currently have:

```
function filterSegments() {
  var myVar = 5;
  for (var i=0; i < segments; i++) {

    clone.children().filter(function(i) {
      return i < myVar;
    ).remove();
  }
}
```

What i want:

```
function filterSegments() {
  var myVar = 5;
  for (var i=0; i < segments; i++) {

    clone.children().filter(myFunc).remove();
  }
}

function myFunc(i, elem, myVar) {
  return i < myVar;
}
```

My Question is, is this even more performant than using an anonymous function over and over again and second question, how can i pass `myFunc()` a variable, like `myVar` without having to declare it as global.

I guess the same concept could apply to jQuery's `each()`

Comment: Is it more performant, no, but it is less code repetition, so it's better and make code smaller. As for the variable thing, you can look for things like `.bind` (native js) or `$.proxy` (jQuery) if you need to support old browser.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get about the same performance; but if you really wanted to you can do a couple other things.

Like set up a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) with a function that returns a function that `.filter` can use:

```
function filterSegments() {
  var myVar = 5;
  for (var i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
    clone.children().filter(myFunc(myVar)).remove();
  }

  function myFunc(max) {
    return function(i) { return i < max; };
  }
}
```

If you want to use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), it will look like:

```
function filterSegments() {
  var myVar = 5;
  for (var i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
    clone.children().filter(myFunc.bind(null, myVar)).remove();
  }

  function myFunc(max, i) {
    return i < max;
  }
}
```

If you wanted to use [ES6 Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
function filterSegments() {
  var myVar = 5;
  for (var i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
    clone.children().filter(j => j < myVar).remove();
  }
}
```

Which is my favorite because it makes it so simple to read and very succinct!

### Edit:

I almost forgot! You can make use of jQuery's [`.remove([selector])`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/#remove-selector) variety:

```
function filterSegments() {
  var myVar = 5;
  for (var i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
    clone.children().remove(':lt(' + myVar + ')');
  }
}
```

and even better (so you don't go through all children) by using [`.children([selector])`](https://api.jquery.com/children/#children-selector) variety:

```
function filterSegments() {
  var myVar = 5;
  for (var i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
    clone.children(':lt(' + myVar + ')').remove();
  }
}
```